# "Tor unexpectedly exited" on MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 Beta

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, mac

I'm having trouble launching Tor Browser on MacOS Mojave 10.14.6 Beta.

I get the "Tor unexpectedly exited" message and haven't been able to launch it. Copying the Tor Logs returns no errors.

Any advice on how to launch Tor successfully?

Comment: thanks! this makes it clear what software you are talking about... **||** how about also copy&pasting the logs here? this may help us to help you, since often `[WARN]`ings and even `[NOTICE]`s contain information to solve problems.

Comment: Hi, thanks for following up. Unfortunately the logs are empty. I'm happy to send any other diagnostic info but I don't know what else I could share that would be useful.

Comment: very "interesting"... sorry, then i'm out because i don't have and can't support a mac.